# Proposition subordonnée implicite?

Tags: syntaxe

Petite question technique pour les grammairiens professionnels.

> Assises confortablement sur un banc, le dialogue commence.

Dans le contexte d'une mère et de sa fille se retrouvant pour discuter. *Assises confortablement sur un banc*, ne peut pas complémenter *le dialogue*, donc implicitement, nous savons que ce sont les 2 personnes qui sont assises et qui initient le dialogue.

Toutefois, la syntaxe de cette phrase est-elle correcte et, si oui, à quel type de proposition subordonnée avons-nous affaire ?

Comment: Bonjour à tous. J'en profite, comme je l'ai oublié dans le texte principal, pour saluer et remercier tous les contributeurs de ce forum. C'est mon premier post, mais j'ai déjà trouvé de nombreuses réponses intéressantes à des interrogations pointues sur les discussions existantes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une *épithète détachée* (LBU14 § 332), en tête de phrase, d'un sujet sous-entendu (la mère et sa fille), peut-être même avec l'ellipse d'un adverbe (*une fois*, qui signifierait non pas la simultanéité mais l'antériorité). On peut aussi comparer à l'*apposition détachée* (LBU § 343) et à une *relative non déterminative* (LBU § 1113) qui partagent certaines des mêmes caractéristiques.

Grevisse et Goosse disent qu'il est « souhaitable » que l'épithète se rapporte au sujet de la phrase ou de la proposition (LBU § 334) mais remarquent que les auteurs « prennent beaucoup de liberté avec cette règle », de diverses manières, incluant des cas où l'épithète « ne se rapporte à aucun élément explicite » :

> A peine DÉBARQUÉS [...], le patron m'appela. (A. Daudet)
> Sitôt SORTIS de Sousse et de l'abri de ses collines, le vent commença de souffler (Gide)
> SEUL avec lui, la conversation est facile (Jouhandeau)

[image]

<sup>Le contexte original, aux [*Éditions Didier*](https://mesmanuels.fr/demo/9782278093106)</sup>

Après une courte amorce de dialogue entre deux personnes, dont une partie renseigne sur un des interlocuteurs (*ma fille*) avec la narration de l'autre interlocuteur, l'épithète détachée au féminin pluriel vient immédiatement compléter l'identification, par inférence grammaticale (féminin pluriel avec *ma fille*, donc une mère et sa fille), et ajoute de l'information tout en créant un pont avec l'omniscience de la narration. Je trouve le tout particulièrement bien ficelé et le propos d'une grande qualité.

Comment: Il ne faut pas suivre les fautes des auteurs ! Les auteurs ne sont pas des dieux de la langue !  https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_autr84vWAiHFbX6w&page=93HYa44F8eTc.html : "N’empêche que ces tours sont souvent perçus comme des licences d’auteur. Les anacoluthes sont toujours un peu à la merci de nos humeurs : la faute de construction de l’un est la figure de style de l’autre.".

Answer (score -2):

Pour que l'on puisse parler de proposition subordonnée (participiale), il faudrait qu'il existe un sujet propre pour le participe passé « assise » ; il n'y en a pas ; donc il s'agit d'un participe passé utilisé comme adjectif. Comme cet adjectif est apposé à « dialogue », ce que l'on considère dans cette phrase, c'est du pur non-sens.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse. C'est intéressant, car en tant que Français et lecteur assidu, cette phrase ne me choque pas mais elle a choqué un collègue vietnamien enseignant de français. Je précise que cette phrase est extraite d'un manuel de français récent, sans pour autant citer de source. Il ne s'agit que d'un court paragraphe, et comme la mère et sa fille sont citées juste avant, pour moi, il est évident qu'_assises_ qualifient ces deux femmes. Je prends donc bonne note de l'incorrection de cette phrase (je n'irais pas jusqu'à non-sens), sous réserve de commentaires argumentés ultérieurs

Comment: @NicoCarotte Du point de vue de ce que l'on devine de l'intention de l'auteur, il y a un sens approximatif, mais il ne correspond pas à la forme. Une fois assises, elle commencent le dialogue ? Pendant qu'elles sont assises le dialogue commence ?

Comment: @NicoCarotte je pense que d'un point de vue purement grammaticale la phrase n'est pas correcte, mais dans un texte elle pourrait sans problème relever de la licence poétique. En gros, ce serait vu comme une "petite erreur volontaire, pour un effet de style".